# debug Perl loop to store data to a reference array

Tags: perl

I have a piece of code like this

```
  foreach my $l(@inarray){
        chop($l);
        if($flag == 0 && $l =~ /^start /){
            my @array01 = split(/\(/,$l);
            $module_name = $array01[0];
            my @array03 = split(/\s/,$array01[-1]);
            $local_data{"module_name"} = $module_name;
            $local_data{"variables"} = \@array03;   
            $flag = 1;
        }
        if($flag == 1 && $l =~ /input/){
            chop($l);
            $l =~ s/input\s+//g;
            my @array01 = split(/,\s/,$l);
            $local_data->{"input"} = \@array01;
        }

        if($flag == 1 && $l =~ /output/){
            chop($l);
            $l =~ s/output\s+//g;
            my @array01 = split(/,\s/,$l);
            $local_data->{"output"} = \@array01;
        }
        if($flag == 1 && $l =~ /end/){         
            push @$infos, $local_data;
            $flag = 0;      
        }
         
}
```

but when I print the @$infos array I saw all the elements of the array are the same as the last element, they are supposed to be different because I'm using the flag to separate them. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: In the first if block you use local_data as a hash and in the rest as hash reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one (global) `$local_data` in this code, so the same object keeps getting   appended to `@$infos`. I think you want to reset `$local_data` each time you encounter the `end` token.

```
push @$infos, $local_data;
$local_data = {};   # or  $local_data = LocalDataThing->new()
```

Or you could easily append a (shallow) copy of `$local_data` each time.

```
push @$infos, {%$local_data};
```

Comment: Adding `%$local_data = ();` to the second approach would be safer.